# ActiveMQ Artemis MQTT Protocol Handler Threading

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using Artemis in embedded mode within my java application as an MQTT broker and have noticed that the `MQTTProtocolHandler` uses the `Actor` class to process the messages asynchronously but this (like `OrderedExecutor`) seems to have a task queue and only ever utilises a single thread to process this task queue (I guess this is for the obvious reason of maintaining order).

The big issue I see here is that we go from multithreaded Netty ingestion of TCP messages to a single threaded MQTT message processor; the MQTT broker throughput is then limited to whatever this single thread can handle; so for example if any blocking IO is performed during message processing (i.e. during authentication and/or authorisation) then the performance is severely limited.

Can someone from the Artemis team shed some light on this as I am struggling to see how this can ever be an MQTT broker that can handle serious amounts of incoming traffic.

Order of messages is only relevant within the scope of a given client ID so I would expect multithreaded support of incoming MQTT publish messages across client IDs (i.e. message grouping based on client ID).

Comment: Do you have a test which demonstrates the bottleneck or is this just theoretical at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the piece that you may be missing is that each MQTT connection gets its own instance of the `MQTTProtocolHandler` and therefore its own `Actor`. This means that multiple MQTT connections can be serviced concurrently. As far as I can tell there is no real bottleneck on the `MQTTProtocolHandler` or the `Actor`.

For what it's worth, the `Actor` mechanism was added via [ARTEMIS-2985](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2985) to actually *increase* performance by freeing Netty to service more connections.

Most MQTT use-cases involve lots of small devices (e.g. IoT) each with their own connection. The broker should be able to handle such connections concurrently. Generally speaking the broker scales pretty well as concurrency increases given the non-blocking core.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! this seems obvious now you mention it. A case of not seeing the wood through the trees whilst load testing with a single client